# Is unlocking a lock_guard manually undefined/bad design?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

I've got code thats something like this:

```
do {
    lock_guard<mutex> lck(globalMtx);
    auto itr = someMap.end();
    for (/*conditions*/){
        //do stuff with itr and someMap
        // if a certain condition is met, we exit function with a return
        // globalMtx needs to be unlocked at that time
    }
    if (itr == someMap.end()){
        // I need to unlock the globalMtx here
        globalMtx.unlock()
        // A command is sent to modify someMap before we try again
        this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::seconds( 5 ) );
    } else {
        break;
    }
} while (true);
```

As you can see in the if scope, I need to unlock the globalMtx so that I can modify "someMap" before going through it again. I've read in many threads/forums/whatever that manually locking a mutex using mutex.lock()/unlock() is a bad idea and typically never done anymore with c++11 or above.

So what can I do in this case to control the mutex as I need, while still preventing any case where leaving the scope keeps the mutex locked?

Comment: Besides the bad design here, the big problem is that you don't lock it again before `lck` going out of scope, which means that `lck` will try to unlock an already unlocked mutex (or, even worse one locked by another thread, since you released it you cannot know if another thread is holding it), which is plain UB in one case, UB + potentially complete pandemonium in the other.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, you should not call `std::mutex::unlock()` directly in this case, as `std::lock_guard` destructor would call `std::mutex::unlock()` again and that would lead to UB. You can use [std::unique_lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) instead, which is not lightweight as `std::lock_guard` but allows you to call `unlock()` on it:

```
std::unique_lock<mutex> lck(globalMtx);
...
lck.unlock(); // lck object is aware that globalMtx is released and would do nothing in it's dtor after this
```

Comment: Does unique_lock work if something else used lock_guard on the same mutex?

Comment: @user1324674: both `lock_guard` and `unique_lock` just use the public API of mutexes, so there's no problem with using `lock_guard` in a function and `unique_lock` on another.

Comment: @user1324674 misunderstood your question, if you mean that other thread uses `lock_guard` then yes, it will work, you do not have to replace it everywhere.

Comment: @Slava that's correct, thats what I meant. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is a bad idea, as the `lock_guard` will still unlock the mutex when it is destroyed, so the mutex will end up being unlocked twice. This results in undefined behaviour (i.e. crash if you're lucky).

Instead, use a `std::unique_lock`. This has an `unlock()` method, which not only calls the `unlock` method of the underlying mutex but also guarantees that the `unique_lock` object will not unlock the mutex a second time.

Answer (score 1):

Write a wrapper like lock_guard that tracks whether the mutex is held or not and only unlocks on destruction if it is held The wrapper should likely have both an unlock and relock (which is a no-op if the lock is already held)..

Comment: I was thinking this exact thing but I wasn't sure if it was encouraged or not, thank you.